# Instrument & Drum Rack disappeared in Ableton

Tags: ableton

I was in the midst of a project and suddenly I noticed my instrument rack and drum rack and other folders are merged into an empty folder that's the name of my current project. I tried going into another project and it was the same. I reinstalled the program, nothing helped. Where did my instruments go and how do I get them back?? :'(

thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwnsQ.png)

Answer (score 2):

In preferences, make sure you look at the library folder. Ableton is library oriented, so make sure you don't put the library in the external hard drive. Also, do not move folders that relate to ableton.